# Tensorflow Inception Model via Flask Memory Leak

Tags: linux, flask, memory-leaks, tensorflow

Below is my code that I'm using to serve Inception-Model via Flask. But unfortunately Linux kills the program in background for memory usage.

From kernel logs, I could find that server.py python program being killed by Linux OOM-Killer as kernel is unable to satisfy the memory requested by other program due insufficient available memory and hence freeing up the memory by choosing to kill the python process.

Please see trace of memory consumed by the process (total_vm). It is close to 1.5GB to 1.7GB which seems to be very high to me.

```
[ pid ]   uid  tgid               total_vm     rss                  nr_ptes swapents            oom_score_adj                name
[ 8640]     0  8640             1654607  1436423          3080      35564                  0                                           python
[32139]    0 32139           1712754  1495071          3195      34153                  0                                           python
[25121]    0 25121           1586597  1390072          2943     9795                    0                                           python

Jun  8 19:15:32 incfs1002 kernel: [16448663.210440] Out of memory: Kill process 8640 (python) score 565 or sacrifice child
Jun  8 19:15:32 incfs1002 kernel: [16448663.211941] Killed process 8640 (python) total-vm:6618428kB, anon-rss:5745664kB, file-rss:28kB

Jun  8 18:21:16 incfs1002 kernel: [16445405.714834] Out of memory: Kill process 32139 (python) score 587 or sacrifice child
Jun  8 18:21:16 incfs1002 kernel: [16445405.714878] Killed process 32139 (python) total-vm:6851016kB, anon-rss:5980284kB, file-rss:0kB

Jun  7 17:40:55 incfs1002 kernel: [16356536.627117] Out of memory: Kill process 25121 (python) score 537 or sacrifice child
Jun  7 17:40:55 incfs1002 kernel: [16356536.627157] Killed process 25121 (python) total-vm:6346388kB, anon-rss:5560164kB, file-rss:124kB
```

Code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import tensorflow as tf

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'


def allowed_file(filename):
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/classify', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def classify_image():
    result = {}
    filename = request.args.get('file')
# Check if filename matches

if filename:
    image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

    label_lines = [line.strip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile("output_labels.txt")]

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Feed the image data as input to the graph an get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                               {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        low_confidence = 0
        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            # print('%s (score = %.2f)' % (human_string, score))
            if score < 0.90:
                low_confidence += 1
            result[human_string] = str(score)

        if low_confidence >= 2:
            result['error'] = 'Unable to classify document type (Passport/Driving License)'

return jsonify(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is the indentation in the code wrong? (It looks like `if filename:` should be part of the function `classify_image()`, but AFAICT the code as written will execute that block once at startup.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but my code is like this:

```
class Classifer
  def __init__(self):
    self.sess = tf.Session()

  def predict(self, image):
    self.sess.run(image)
```

I can't say whether or not flask with caffe has the same problem.

I solved the problem using *`gunicorn`*:

```
gunicorn \
  --reuse-port \
  -b ${host}:${port} \
  --reload  \
  --log-level debug \
  --workers 2 \
  --max-requests 10000 \
  --max-requests-jitter 200 \
```

Note that *max-requests* sets the server to restart after 10000 calls.